# is there a faster way make this mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

the query below matches each model up with their associated photo shoot and lets me echo out 10 post with the first image in the photo shoot as the default image for the post. while it works fine, it seems to be really slow. is there a faster way of achieving the desired results?

```
"SELECT * "
. "FROM models a "
. "INNER JOIN models_images b ON a.model_id = b.model_id "
. "WHERE 1 AND `images_ok` = '1'"       
. "GROUP BY a.model_id ORDER BY a.id DESC "     
. "LIMIT 10"
```

Thanks

Comment: Why `WHERE 1`, only use `"WHERE images_ok = '1'`

Comment: not sure what "WHERE 1" means, I didn't build this query, but after taking it out, the page still loads pretty slow with this query, not sure it made a difference

Comment: It will give you all results if you use `WHERE 1`.

Comment: Define slow (how long does it take and how many elements do you have in the tables). What is the structure (the indexes and the types of the columns are important to know)? Why do you use `GROUP BY`  (what do you expect it to do in your query)?

Comment: well without that query on the page, the page loads instantly, but with that query only the page, it actually takes over 5 seconds to load, even if you change the "LIMIT" to a 3 or 4 instead of 10.

Comment: It's obvious to me why the `WHERE 1` is there. In the backend that generates the query, there are multiple `if` statements that can optionally add WHERE clauses. There are probably lots of: `if x then query += " AND blah"`. It would be cumbersome to figure out which one comes first and remove the "AND", so it's easier to start off with `WHERE 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add indexes on `model_id` and `images_ok` fields in both tables.

Like this:

```
--           table name         new index name     field name
ALTER TABLE `models` ADD INDEX `models_model_id` (`model_id`);
```

Wikipedia about database indexes:

> A **database index** is a data structure that improves the speed of
>   data retrieval operations on a database table at the cost of slower
>   writes and the use of more storage space. Indexes can be created using
>   one or more columns of a database table, providing the basis for both
>   rapid random lookups and efficient access of ordered records.

Good video that may help with understanding indexes:

[Understanding Indexes by solubletech at youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8oBKA4hU4xM)

Comment: where is the `models_model_id` coming from?

Comment: It's just index name. You have to name it somehow (to be able to delete/update it later). Im using names like this: `tablename_fieldname`, but you can use any name.

Comment: so after I do that, do I still run the same query? or do I have to make any changes in the query?

Comment: There is no need to change query. Index just adds something like "invisible" field in background, and that field contains something similar to record position after sorting that table by indexed field. Database engine is able to find specyfic values faster (all happends in background), but when you are inserting or updating rows - database must calculate index value, so operations like insert or update are a little bit slower.

Comment: worked perfectly!!!!!!!!!!!!!! page loads 10x faster! you have no idea how much I appreciate the help, I can definately say I just learned something new lol

Comment: Maybe you have to read some manuals or tutorials about databases ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql's feature "index" for this solution . please refer mysql manual for a detail explanation on indexes

See [Mysql developer tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html)

Or

See [W3chools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp)